# Creating a custom Panel class C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Hey guys, I'm trying to set up a custom Panel called FormPanel from Panel

```
class FormPanel : Panel
    {
        bool previous;
        FormPanel l;

        public FormPanel()
        {
            previous = false;
            l.Parent = this;
            l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
    }
```

This is pretty much where I am right now. I want the FormPanel to have a bool var and want to set it's default properties of Parent and Dock. How does this work? How can I set those?

Comment: What the purpose of setting .Parent to "this"?

Comment: This code is not close.  As is, it bombs with a NullReferenceException.  When you fix that, it will bomb with OutOfMemoryException.  The `l` member needs to go, it is quite unclear why it even exists.  Also forget about setting the Parent property.

Comment: I was looking for answers on this for a quite a while and bumped on to this stuff. I tried it, it didn't work but I left it in, in case it's useful in anyway. I answered about what I want with all this under the answer if you can look at it it would be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want your panel to have DockStyle.Fill as default for the Dock property, do this:

```
public class FormPanel : Panel
{
    public FormPanel()
    {
        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(DockStyle), "Fill")]
    public override DockStyle Dock
    {
        get { return base.Dock; }
        set { base.Dock = value; }
    }
}
```

This makes the Dock property default to Fill within the property window.

Comment: I'm using this for now, and just set Parent manually, if there is no better approach this is good, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Regarding setting the parent, Joe provided something that will work. You can't set the parent of the control from within your control, unless it gets passed in there within the constructor.

Comment: (... hit the five minute editing boundary ...) But you can't really use that constructor unless you create the controls on your form dynamically. The constructor for your FormPanel is being called from within InitializeComponent() in a Form, and that code is auto-generated by Visual Studio and shouldn't be touched. Even if you were able to pass a parent at this point, I think adding your control to the Form's controls collection sets the Control's parent to the Form (unless, of course, it's contained within another container control).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an internal variable of your type, instead set the properties (that you inherit from the baseclass) directly:

```
class FormPanel : Panel
{
    bool previous;

    public FormPanel()
    {
        previous = false;
        base.Parent = this;
        base.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }
}
```

although I don't think that "base.Parent=this" will work ...

Comment: Thanks. I've just started using these things so it's bit hard :) So I can't really set Parent just manually?

Comment: You could set the parent, but what do you expect to happen when the parent is the control itself? Some properties also look at the parent to find their value - those will go into an endless loop this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more info about what you're trying to achieve.

As it stands your FormPanel has a private field (l) which is itself a FormPanel:

```
  FormPanel l;
```

You never instantiate this field, so it will always be null, and the assignments to properties in the constructor will fail with a `NullReferenceException`:

```
l.Parent = this;              
l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

If you did instantiate this private field, you would have recursion, since your FormPanel contains a private FormPanel, which itself contains a private FormPanel, ...

```
l = new FormPanel();
l.Parent = this;              
l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

You say you want to set a default Parent, but I don't see how a FormPanel can know what it's parent is in the constructor, unless you pass the parent as a parameter to the constructor, e.g. maybe you're looking for something like:

```
public FormPanel() : this(null)
{
}

public FormPanel(Control parent)
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
    this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try messing with the settings

Comment: I have a MenuStrip where you can click on different things for example: EditMenu or Login. Each time you click on one of those I want to Show the corresponding Panel EditMenu -> EditPanel Login -> LoginPanel. I want to give them a boolean value "previous" so I will know which one of them needs Hide() before Show()ing the new one. Maybe there is an easier way, this is what I came up with.